# How to set the border color of the dots in matplotlib's scatterplots?

Tags: graphics, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

Is it possible to set the color of the borders of the dots that are generated via the `Axes.scatter` or is it always black?

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to make all the edges the same color:

```
ax.scatter(...., edgecolor=EC)
```

where `EC` is a color.  If you want to surpress the edge (so it looks like the edge color matches the face color) use

```
ax.scatter(..., linewidths=0)
```

If you want to have the edges be a different color than the face and each marker have it's own color it looks like you have to do the mapping your self:

```
my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()
ec_data = rand(15)
my_normed_data = my_norm(ec_data)
ec_colors = my_cmap(my_normed_data) # a Nx4 array of rgba value
ax.scatter(rand(15), rand(15), s=500, c=rand(15), edgecolors=ec_colors, linewidth=3)
```

[image]